# Typescript factory class using logic

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a typescript class inheriting another one. I would like to create a factory class that creates an object of one  or the other using basic logic, but it is not working.

This is a basic class for a Customer:

```
class Customer {
  static member = true;
  id:string;
  static c_type = "Basic Customer";

  makeTransaction():string {
    var transaction_id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    console.log(this.constructor.toString().split ('(' || /s+/)[0].split (' ' || /s+/)[1]);
    return transaction_id;
  }

  constructor(public name:string, public dob:string) {
    this.id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  }

}
```

This class extends customers to create a VIP customer:

```
class VIPCustomer extends Customer{
  vip_num:string;
  vip_discount:number;
  static c_type = "VIP Customer";
  constructor(public name:string, public dob:string) {
    super(name, dob);
    this.vip_num = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  }
}
```

The customer creator is intended to create either a VIP customer or regular customer based on a string comparison, but it is not working.

```
class CustomerCreator {
  static create(event: {name:string; dob: string}, type:string) {
    console.log('Log type' + typeof type);
    if (type === 'Basic') {
      console.log('basic customer created');
      return new Customer(event.name, event.dob);
    }
    if (type === 'VIP') {
      console.log('basic customer created');
      return new VIPCustomer(event.name, event.dob);
    }
  }
}
console.log(Customer.c_type);
console.log(VIPCustomer.c_type);
const customer_1 = CustomerCreator.create({name:'Pii', dob:'03/19'}, 'VIP');
var customer_2 = CustomerCreator.create({name:'Matthew', dob:'12/70'}, 'Basic');

//accessing an attribute
console.log(customer_1.name);
console.log(customer_1.id);
//console.log(customer_1.vip_num)
```

If you uncomment the last print statement, the code does not compile. The print statements also indicate that a basic customer is being created for both the customers 1 and 2, despite the string comparison. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not working because the `create` factory method always returns the type `Customer` as `VIPCustomer` is also derived from `Customer`. Also, your `create` function not only returns just `Customer` but `Customer | undefined` because you do not have a default case (when type is neither `Basic` or `VIP`). I would just create multiple factory methods for each type of customer. In this case of my example there is almost no shared piece of code or extra processing, the factory pattern is rendered useless.

```js
class CustomerCreator {
    static create(event: { name: string; dob: string }) {
        return new Customer(event.name, event.dob);
    }

    static createVip(event: { name: string; dob: string }) {
        return new VIPCustomer(event.name, event.dob);
    }
}
console.log(Customer.c_type);
console.log(VIPCustomer.c_type);
const customer_1 = CustomerCreator.createVip({ name: 'Pii', dob: '03/19' });
var customer_2 = CustomerCreator.create({ name: 'Matthew', dob: '12/70' });

console.log(customer_1.name);
console.log(customer_1.id);
console.log(customer_1.vip_num)
```

Comment: Updated my answer to include explanation

Answer (score 2):

Typescript only has type info of compiling time, but not type info only known in run time.

The return type of `CustomerCreator.create` is `Customer|VIPCustomer` which is narrowed down to `Customer` so everything return from that function is recognized to ts compiler as `Customer` . That's the whole point of Factory pattern, that your code rely on interface but not class

If you really want to let compiler know what exact type of what `CustomerCreator.create` returns, you could try following code

```js
type CreatorResult = {
    Basic: Customer,
    VIP: VIPCustomer
}

class CustomerCreator {
  static create<T extends 'Basic'| 'VIP'>(event: {name:string; dob: string}, type:T): CreatorResult[T] {
```

although this is not recommended

Comment: why isn't this recommended?

Comment: it's misuse of Typescript's mapped types, and expose too much details to caller